# how to install binary package from github in R

Tags: r, installation, binary, package

I have an R binary package in github.
The following code does not work.
Could any one can help me to install this.

`devtools::install_github('yikeshu0611/set',type = 'binary')`

Greate tahnks.

Answer (score 0):

for me the package doesn't exist. I checked the Repos list also for yikeshu0611 at
https://github.com/yikeshu0611?after=Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpK0MjAyMC0wMy0wMlQxMzoxNzo0OVrODpDEKg%3D%3D&tab=repositories

But there is not "nhanesR" there. Please check.

```
> devtools::install_github('yikeshu0611/nhanesR',type = 'binary')
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 404.
  Not Found

  Did you spell the repo owner (`yikeshu0611`) and repo name (`nhanesR`) correctly?
  - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.
```

Comment: sorry@anuanand, I changed the command to `devtools::install_github('yikeshu0611/set',type = 'binary')` greate thanks